# Не получается запустить 2 функции параллельно

Tags: python, многопоточность, asyncio

При попытке запустить 2 асинхронные функции в разных потоках возникает либо ошибка, что функции не ожидаются, либо первая функция блокирует вторую при выполнении задач.

Код:

```py
async def EventsHandler():
    print("Поток с ивентами запущен")
    while True:
        ...


async def StartBot():
    print("Бот запущен")
    bot.run(TOKEN)


async def Start():
    ...
    # Здесь запуск 2-х параллельных асинхронных функции


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for ext in extensions:
        bot.load_extension(ext)
        logger.debug(f"Module '{str(ext)}' loaded")

    asyncio.run(Start())
```

По идеи должно работать так, чтобы я вызывал через if **name** функцию Start(), далее из этой функции создавалось 2 потока: StartBot() и EventsHandler().
Но в двух вариантов этой реализации возникает 2 ошибки:

1. Если попытаться добавить этот код в Start(), то вылазит ошибка **coroutine 'to_thread' was never awaited**

```py
async def Start():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        task_one = loop.run_in_executor(executor, asyncio.to_thread, StartBot)
        task_two = loop.run_in_executor(executor, asyncio.to_thread, EventsHandler)

        await asyncio.gather(task_one, task_two)
```

2. Если попытаться через asyncio.gather, то вот что выдает в консоль:

```
RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running
Поток с ивентами запущен
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
```

И вот сам код:

```py
async def Start():
    bot_task = asyncio.create_task(StartBot())
    events_task = asyncio.create_task(EventsHandler())

    await asyncio.gather(bot_task, events_task)
```

И у меня никак больше не получается запустить 2 таска, чтобы они не мешали друг другу. Мне нужно, чтобы у меня работала функция EventsHandler, которая не будет блокировать bot.run()

Comment: Не нужно to_thread дополнительно в экзекьютор отправлять, он сам же внутри запускает код через экзекьютор. Пробуйте просто `task_one = asyncio.to_thread(StartBot)`, при этом StartBot сделайте синхронной функцией. См. пример в документации: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-in-threads

Comment: что внутри EventsHandler ?